# How do I catch an event when flask-socketio decides to delete a socketio session?

Tags: session, websocket, flask-socketio

Heads up: flask-socketio sessions are not User Sessions mentioned below.

I'm restructuring my React app to handle multiple `User Sessions` defined by a string in the URL. Whenever a browser tab/window connects to the server with the `User Session` in its URL, I will record it as a connection of that `User Session`, and multiple connections of the same `User Session` will be stored in a list.

I found `request.sid` might be the right thing to identify these connections I mentioned, and I can add the value of `request.sid` to the list whenever a new connection from a browser tab/window is built. Each tab/window is assigned a different such `sid`, i.e. socketio session id, and multiple socketio session ids belong to a single `User Session` of my definition.

However, I don't know when a browser connection is lost due to internet disconnection. Usually, it's handled by heartbeat mechanism, and flask-socketio already has a heartbeat built in, so I'm wondering whether I can catch an event when the built-in heartbeat finally exceeds the expiration time, so that I can go ahead and delete the `sid` from the connection list.

Any ideas/suggestions for me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I’m checking the engineio user sessions: https://python-engineio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html#user-sessions.  If I can use engineio api when I use flask-socketio, I may be able to utilize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the `disconnect` event:

```
@socketio.on('disconnect')
def client_disconnected():
    # remove request.sid from your application state
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! I have been using 'disconnect event' copied from a client side event catching example. That's why I didn't get the correct result.